# Linq to Sql DataContext life cycle in a WCF service

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, datacontext, lifecycle, object-lifetime

I have a service exposed via WCF. The service exposes several methods that talk to the database through a Linq to SQL datacontext. The datacontext is bound to the CallContext. All of this is working as it should but I can't figure out the proper place to dispose the Linq to SQL datacontext. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean when say "bound to the CallContext"?

Comment: CallContext.SetData("DataContext", new ModelContext());

Answer (score 1):

I've found this [Unit of Work](http://blog.codeville.net/2007/11/29/linq-to-sql-the-multi-tier-story/) approach really helpful. The blog post explains very well the trade-offs between the options. Also, you might want to check [this post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx) that deals with threading issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that best practice is to create and dispose Linq to SQL context in every call.

```
public void DoSomething(){

   using(var c = new MoldeContext()){
       // Do something..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. I'll mark this as the answer if there isn't a better one by tomorrow. I used the `OperationContext.Current.OperationCompleted` event to dispose the DataContext.

Answer (score -1):

In this post Stephen Walther says  that we should not Dispose the DataContext
http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t.aspx